# Como crear y modificar una cookie con JavaScript

Tags: javascript, cookies

Tengo un problema al tratar de crear y modificar una cookie, no estoy seguro si lo estoy haciendo bien, al tratar de leer la informacion de la cookie me aparece en blanco como si no existiera. Este es mi codigo:

```
window.onload = iniciar;
function iniciar()
 {
    document.cookie = "usuario = pepito perez;";
    var miCookie = document.cookie;  
    document.getElementById("Label1").innerHTML=miCookie;
    alert(miCookie);
 }
```

Tambien tengo un boton en el HTML que al hacer click llama a la siguiente función:

```
function modCookie()
{
    document.cookie = "usuario = Zork gomez;";
    document.getElementById("Label1").innerHTML=miCookie;
    alert(document.cookie);
}
```

Comment: Creo que no debes dejar el espacio en blanco en la asignación del par `clave=valor`. Prueba eso y comentas. Saludos

Comment: @MauricioContreras ya quite los espacios en blanco y tambien agregué el campo age pero a la hora de leer la cookie aparece en blanco.

Answer (score 0):

Intenta añadiendo un campo "age" en la cookie y en la ruta. También recomiendo de eliminar los espacios en blanco.

Intenta esto:

```
document.cookie = "usuario=pepito perez;max-age=3600;path=/";
```